# composer is not updating

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to update my composer but it is showing fatal error like:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-fly>composer update
```

> Warning: This development build of composer is over 60 days old. It is
>   recommended to update it by running
>   "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar self-update" to get
>   the latest version.

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

> Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not
>   found in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-fly\artisan on line 34 Script php
>   artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with
>   an error

and i tried

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-fly>C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar self-update
```

but its not updating. please help me...

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling composer?

Comment: update your composer with this command: composer update --self

Comment: As far as I can see it is updating, but it can't clear the cache. I had the same problem with installing Symfony 3 and the new autoloading method. Maybe this is the same problem? Take a look at app/console: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/commit/0e8094a09565d0e2604b00b1368f34a8dce7c0e2. If not, please let us know which version of Laravel you're using.

Comment: thanks i reinstalled composer and it worked